# Unable to pass value through Intent from Child Activity (Google Maps) to Parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I simply want to retrieve the latitude and longitude values from Google Maps (children activity) using onActivityResult to pass it back to the parent activity. However the retrieved value seems to always return a 0. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Parent Activity:

```
 Intent intent;
 intent = new Intent(TheInput.this, GoogleMap.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
 break;
 ...
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 5){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("LATITUDE",0);
                longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("LONGITUDE",0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "From the received data, \nLat is " + latitude + ", Lon is " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                 //The toast value shows 0
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Child Activity (Google Maps):

```
List<Address> locationList = null;
Address address = locationList.get(0);
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
lat = address.getLatitude();
lon = address.getLongitude();

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("LATITUDE",lat);
intent.putExtra("LONGITUDE",lon);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat is " + lat + ", Lon is " + lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//The toast shows that they are values here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my mistake, this portion of code in the Parent Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 5){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("LATITUDE",0);
                longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("LONGITUDE",0);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

is supposed to be written like this instead.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 5){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                latitude = data.getDoubleExtra("LATITUDE",0);
                longitude = data.getDoubleExtra("LONGITUDE",0);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```